# Where to put a single menu item on a Windows form

Tags: design, user-centered-design, windows-os

This is more of a design question than a technical one. I am developing a Windows application with a menu bar and toolbar. I have menu items for the File, Tools, and Help menus, but I have a few other menu items that are important to the application (Search, for one) that don't seem to fit. I think it is bad practice to just put Search as a menu item by itself, as shown:

File | Search | Tools | Help

Because every other menu is NOT clickable, and opens a drop down with more menu choices, and the Search would be clickable, and launch the Search. Originally, I had several Search choices, but the design has changed to now have a single Search option. Any suggestions for another top-level name, or other ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Notepad for some ideas. Normally, menus don't have only one option, but there really isn't a reason for them not to. Alternatively, just put it in the Tools menu, because it *is* a tool after all.

Answer (score 2):

The menu should be for menus, not clickable buttons.

The normal way to highlight search is to have a search box (which could be on the right of the menu bar, or in the toolbar).

You could, additionally, put it into one of the other menus for completeness (`File -> Search` and `Tools -> Search` both potentially make sense).